# Access Violation: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Tags: c#, object, indexing, foreach

I have the following variable: _Data.

The variable contains the following info:
[_Data Variable](http://oi67.tinypic.com/drbg2p.jpg)

How can i access the message field?

I tried `_Data["messages"][0]` - but it not wokring.

I recieved the following error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The Image doesn't load.Can you place the code directly in the question itself?

Comment: @Steven, i fixed the link.

Comment: Please input further information about your variable. What type is it? Why should it have an indexer? For now i'm guessing you are using a List of KeyValuePair which could be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am i doing wrong?

```
_Data["messages"]
```

is returning type `object`. You need to cast it to `List<string>` or `IList<string>` in order to use an indexer.

```
var indexable = _Data["messages"] as IList<string>; // The image is cut off - not sure if this should be string or not
if (indexable != null)
    return indexable[0];
```